# IIS basic auth and object permissions

Tags: iis, basic-authentication

I've got an issue and it is one of those where I'm not even sure how to ask the question.

We have a web site the uses basic authentication through IIS 7 (Windows 2007 server SP2) and everything works fine except for a com object. The object is "easyPDF.PDFProcessor.7" in case anyone knows of it.

The problem is that when I authenticate using regular user credentials this object throws an error 2147155963 and fails with the message "unable to open output file". I'm sure the message and error are specific to the object but it points to a permissions issue.

However, if I login using my admin credentials there is no problem and the process runs perfectly. I can't even seem to phrase a search correctly to find out how the login credentials affect the permissions of the object.

I have the directory in question set so that "everyone", "authenticated users", the user created for the object itself (which is also in the admin group), "users", and "IIS_IUSRS" all have full control.

I really have no idea what to even look at from here. IF anyone can shed any light on it or point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Looking at their SDK change log, easyPDF has a mode that uses temporary files. Are you using that mode, and if so, did you give permissions to the temporary folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Process Monitor from SysInternals to see where the permissions are failing.

Download Process Monitor:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

An article on detecting permissions issues in IIS using Process Monitor:
http://www.iislogs.com/steveschofield/detecting-permission-issues-using-auditing-and-process-monitor

Comment: Thanks for the replies...No, we're not using the temp method so I dont think that that is the problem. I did download preocessmonitor and am playing with that but it isn't showing me anything either, neither is the security event log or even the iis logs. The whole thing is very frustrating. I'll keep poking around though...

Comment: How about a license file or registry setting, could it be checking for that? I'd be more than a little concerned if nothing was showing up in Process Monitor. Any chance of switching to iTextSharp and getting rid of the COM object?

Answer (score 0):

IT was the temp directory as Jadarnel27 suggested, I swear I looked at it yesterday but maybe I looked at my user temp and not the windows temp. Either way, all I did was add 'Authenticated Users' to it and it is now working.

Thanks everyone!!

I've learned a bit more about process monitor now as well! :)